# Error "Cannot Implicitly Convert Type" when accessing Publication Metadata Category

Tags: razor, metadata, tridion

I had a similar question before, but this is a few steps beyond that so here we go:

I am trying to access values in a category in Tridion 2011. I am using the Razor TBB and using this code to do it:

```
@foreach (var keyword in Publication.MetaData.myCategory) {
  @: Hello World!
}
```

I have set up a metadata schema with a field that has an xml name of "myCategory" attached to my publication. If I run this on the publication where myCategory is a Text field, this code works... kind of. It treats EACH character as a separate value of the keyword variable... so if I enter the text "one", what prints is "Hello World! Hello World! Hello World!", and if I just have "o" as the value, it prints "Hello World!".

Bizarre as that is (and I'd like to know why on that too), what I really want the field to be a "Values will be selected from a list" type of field, pointing to my category in Categories and keywords. When I do this, and the value of myCategory changes to the value of the item selected in the dropdown for this type of field instead of direct text entry, the code no longer works and gives this error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'Tridion.Extensions.Mediators.Razor.Models.KeywordModel' to 'System.Collections.IEnumerable'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you get your output repeated for every character in a string, you are clearly iterating over the characters in the string and not the other range of values that you expected.

I quickly checked the relevant code of the Razor mediator and its `ToString` method indeed returns the Title of the underlying `RepositoryLocalObject`.

http://code.google.com/p/razor-mediator-4-tridion/source/browse/trunk/Tridion.Extensions.Mediators.RazorMediator/Tridion.Extensions.Mediators.RazorMediator/Models/AbstractRepositoryLocalObject.cs

http://code.google.com/p/razor-mediator-4-tridion/source/browse/trunk/Tridion.Extensions.Mediators.RazorMediator/Tridion.Extensions.Mediators.RazorMediator/Models/KeywordModel.cs

http://code.google.com/p/razor-mediator-4-tridion/source/browse/trunk/Tridion.Extensions.Mediators.RazorMediator/Tridion.Extensions.Mediators.RazorMediator/Models/DynamicItemFields.cs

The code that handles KeywordFields in in the `DynamicItemsFields.cs` file:

```
else if (itemField is KeywordField)
{
    KeywordField keywordField = (KeywordField)itemField;
    if (keywordField.Definition.MaxOccurs == 1)
        if (keywordField.Value == null)
            _dictionary[key] = null;
        else
            _dictionary[key] = new KeywordModel(_engine, keywordField.Value);
    else
    {
        List<KeywordModel> keywords = new List<KeywordModel>();
        int i = 0;
        foreach (Keyword k in keywordField.Values)
        {
            var kw = new KeywordModel(_engine, k);
            kw.Index = i++;
            kw.IsLast = Index == keywordField.Values.Count - 1;
            keywords.Add(kw);
        }
        _dictionary[key] = keywords;
    }
}
```

So it looks like the `myCategory` property will either be a KeywordModel object (if the KeywordField is single-value) or a `List<KeywordModel>` (if the KeywordField is marked as multi-value in the Schema). Is your `myCategory` field single value? Or multi-value?

If it is single-value, what type of output were your expecting? If you were expecting the list of **allowed values** (instead of the **currently selected value**), check if you can access it through `myCategory.Definition` somehow (which should be a regular TOM.NET `KeywordFieldDefinition` object).

Comment: It is marked as single value. Invoking ToString() on the end of keyword variable seems to have cleared things up. This code returns the value of the item, but my Hello World test still indicates that though it now works, it is still going through each character and then combining them at the end. Thank you though this portion works now, and I'm one step closer!

Comment: Since your `myCategory` is single-value, your code will iterate over the characters in the string. There is nothing wrong there, it does exactly what you tell it to do. It seems that you want to iterate over the allowed keywords in the category, in which case you should follow the `Definition` property on myCategory and work from there. Just look at the TOM.NET API docs, which seemed quite clear when I just checked them.